# "If" tag in <VIRTUAL_HOST> of httpd.conf file checking HTTP_UESR_AGENT of apache 2.4 not working as expected

Tags: apache, redirect, if-statement, user-agent, httpd.conf

I found out from documentation that from Apache 2.3 onwards we can use 
tag in hattpd.conf file.

But when tried following in my httpd.conf file, I am not able to get required redirection.

part of httpd.conf file is as follows:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName localhost:80
       ServerAlias localhost1
       <If "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} == 'iphone'">
          RewriteEngine on

          Redirect / http://172.26.50.246:90/
       </If>

       DocumentRoot "C:/Apache24/htdocs"
    </VirtualHost>
```

Please help me in finding flaw in above sniplet...
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution

```
#-strmatch
<If "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} -strcmatch '*iphone*'">
    Redirect / http://172.26.50.246:90/
</If>
```